# How to mix multiple different frequency tones into one

Tags: python, audio, frequency, pyaudio, audio-processing

I want to create an audio tone which consists of multiple frequency audios ranging from 2kHz-3kHz using python.

I created these functions to generate audio consisting of 2 tones of different frequency

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write


def generate_hightone():
    samplerate = 44100; fs = 2000
    time = 0.5
    t = np.linspace(0., time, round(samplerate*time))
    amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    data = amplitude * np.sin(2. * np.pi * fs * t)
    data = np.int16(data/np.max(np.abs(data)) * 32767)
    return data


def generate_lowtone():
    samplerate = 44100; fs = 2200
    time = 0.5
    t = np.linspace(0., time, round(samplerate*time))
    amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    print(amplitude)
    data = amplitude * np.sin(2. * np.pi * fs * t)
    data = np.int16(data/np.max(np.abs(data)) * 32767)
    return data


def freq_mixer(freq1,freq2):
    print(len(freq1),len(freq2))
    return np.round(freq1*0.5).astype(int) + np.round(freq2*0.5).astype(int)


data = freq_mixer(generate_hightone(),generate_lowtone())

write("example.wav", samplerate, data)
```

From this audio is saved but when I am playing this audio no tone is playing. When I save only single tone it is playing a sound but in case of mixing(output of freq_mixer) no sound is there.

Is there any other way of mixing multiple freq audio?

Output tone should be like this on [spectrogram](https://auditoryneuroscience.com/acoustics/spectrogram)[image: https://auditoryneuroscience.com/acoustics/spectrogram]

Comment: Surely you just need to add the two arrays element-wise.

Comment: If you can run this code you will find no sound output on example.wav file why is it happening then?

Comment: I think you're using `int` which just collapses every value to `0`?

Comment: without using ```int``` the audio player shows it a corrupted file

Comment: So, how did you manage to save a single tone?

Comment: Did you try just `freq1 // 2 + freq2 // 2`? That should work.

Comment: @zvone It worked actually I don't know why converting them into ```int``` after multiplying isn't working.

Comment: @quamrana I saved only output of ```generate_hightone()```.

Comment: @astrick Because `int` is not the same as `int16`. I explained below in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio data should contain `int16` values, because it is 16-bit audio.

The original tones are converted to `int16` here:

```
data = np.int16(data/np.max(np.abs(data)) * 32767)
```

On the other hand, the mixer creates an `int` (which is same as `int64`) rather than `int16`, here:

```
np.round(freq1*0.5).astype(int) + np.round(freq2*0.5).astype(int)
```

Converting it to `int16` would probably work, but it is in fact easier and faster to never go from `int16` to float in the first place and simply do this instead:

```
freq1 // 2 + freq2 // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the frequency mixer to `float` or do a simple addition of the tones:

```
def freq_mixer(freq1,freq2):
    print(len(freq1),len(freq2))
    return np.round(freq1*0.5).astype(float) + np.round(freq2*0.5).astype(float)


data1 = generate_hightone()
data2 = generate_lowtone()
data3 = data1+data2 #simpler addition
data3 = freq_mixer(generate_hightone(),generate_lowtone())
samplerate = 80000
write("example.wav", samplerate, data3)
```

Comment: audio player is showing error "This item was encoded in a format that's not supported."

Comment: works fine for me, try updating `scipy` and `numpy` in a fresh Python environment? Or use a different media player